# ошибка во время запуска программ на ос debian

Tags: debian, sublime-text

```
root@debian:~/Загрузки/sublime_text_3# ls
changelog.txt   Icon      plugin_host    sublime_plugin.py  sublime_text
crash_reporter  Packages  python3.3.zip  sublime.py     sublime_text.desktop
root@debian:~/Загрузки/sublime_text_3# ./sublime_text
bash: ./sublime_text: не удаётся запустить бинарный файл: Ошибка формата выполняемого файла
root@debian:~/Загрузки/sublime_text_3# uname -a
Linux debian 4.19.0-21-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.19.249-2 (2022-06-30) i686 GNU/Linux
root@debian:~/Загрузки/sublime_text_3#
```

Не могу редактор запустить, как поправить? ось кривая или лыжи не едут?